# Are there any alternative solutions to "Django smart select" capable of filtering a ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

As the Title and the included link pretty much say it all, I would extend the question with unnecessary examples.

I have searched on this subject wide and far, but even though this [question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191026/how-can-i-use-django-smart-select-to-filter-manytomanyfield), there was either no answer or, as I am new to Django (although I have a background in Python, PHP and JavaScript) the answer was beyond my level.

Safe to say that at this point I don't even know where to start so any suggestions on how this might be achieved would be most gratefully received

Comment: Dynamic filtering of a select field, basically? All solutions are going to require an AJAX interface to do the filter. If you're looking for an alternative to that, you're out of luck. Otherwise, please be more specific about what you really want to achieve (or avoid as the case may be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking to do, if I understand your question correctly, can be done, if you use: http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/

Comment: I want to use this ajax in admin page drop down menu list .. How to do that ?